# unite testing in .net core 2.0 with Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, xunit

I have controller with DI approach.want to test each action of controller using unit testing.
**Controller **

```
  public SearchController(ILookupSearch lookupSearch, IFullSearch fullSearch, IEmpUow uow, ILogger<SearchController> logger, TelemetryClient telemetryClient, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, IOptions<ConnectionStringsConfig> connectionString, IOptions<AppSettingsConfig> options)
    {
        this.LookupSearch = lookupSearch;
        this.FullSearch = fullSearch;
        this.EmpUow = uow;
        this.logger = logger;
        this.hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        this.connectionString = connectionString.Value;
        this.appSettings = options.Value;
        this.telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
    }


    [Route("Test")]
        [ActionName("Test")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Test()
        {
if(this.appsettings.enableDummyData){
            return this.SearchEmpData(new EmpIdQueryField() { Country = "Sweden", EMPID = 441150 });
           }
        }
```

call goes to controller but all dependencies values in constructor are null.

Unit test case

```
   public async void Test1()
    {

        //Arrange

        Mock<IHostingEnvironment> hostingEnvironment = new Mock<IHostingEnvironment>();
        TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
        Mock<ILogger<SearchController>> logger = new Mock<ILogger<SearchController>>();
        Mock<AppSettingsConfig> appSettings = new Mock<AppSettingsConfig>();

        Mock<IOptions<ConnectionStringsConfig>> connectionString = new Mock<IOptions<ConnectionStringsConfig>>();
        Mock<IOptions<AppSettingsConfig>> options = new Mock<IOptions<AppSettingsConfig>>();

        Mock<ILookupSearch> lookupSearch = new Mock<ILookupSearch>();
        Mock<IFullSearch> fullSearch = new Mock<IFullSearch>();
        Mock<IOneSoeUow> EmpUow = new Mock<IEmpUow>();

        //Act
        SearchController search = new SearchController(lookupSearch.Object, fullSearch.Object, oneSoeUow.Object, logger.Object, telemetryClient, hostingEnvironment.Object, connectionString.Object, options.Object);
        search.Test();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Test` action you are consuming `appsettings` property, you need to setup appsettings instance in mock object,

```
    Mock<IOptions<AppSettingsConfig>> options = new Mock<IOptions<AppSettingsConfig>>();
    options.Setup(e=>e.appsettings).Returns(new Appsettings(){ enableDummyData = true });
```

It will mock `enableDummyData` to true,

Likewise, you need to setup all other properties of dependencies which you are consuming in this action or in other actions

Comment: Tried the same but got error:  'Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: a => a.SWITCH_ENABLE_DUMMY_DATA'